# Show if $\|\cdot\|$ is a norm then $\|f(\cdot)\|$ is a norm where $f$ is linear and invertible

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis, normed-spaces

I want to show that if $\|\cdot\|$ is a norm then $\|f(\cdot)\|$ is a norm where $f$ is a linear and invertible function.

First I need to show if $x\neq0$ then $\|f(x)\|>0$. Since $f$ is invertible $f(x)=0 \iff x=0$. Then since $\|\cdot\|$ is a norm it is true.

Next I need to show $\|f(\lambda x)\| = |\lambda|\|f(x)\|$:
By the linearity of $f$, $\|f(\lambda x)\| = \|\lambda f(x)\|$. Since $\|\cdot\|$ is a norm it is true.

Finally we need to show the triangle inequality. Starting with the linearity of $f$, $\|f(x+y)\|=\|f(x)+f(y)\|$. Since $\|\cdot\|$ is a norm we can write:
\begin{equation}                                                                \|f(x)+f(y)\| \leq \|f(x)\| + \|f(y)\|                                                                        \end{equation}
and thus we have shown the triangle inequality.

1.Is it sufficient to conclude in every case "since $\|\cdot\|$ is a norm it is true"?

1.What would make this proof clearer?

Comment: This looks good to me. The only thing to make it clearer is to put the whole triangle inequality on one line, as $$\|f(x+y)\| = \|f(x) + f(y)\| \leq \|f(x)\| + \|f(y)\|,$$ and mention that the last inequality is simply the triangle inequality for $\|\cdot\|$. And if you'd like you can write something like $\|\cdot\|_f = \|f(\cdot)\|$, though I don't think it's necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write it more compactly (following the comment by Andrew Poelstra): for all $x,y\in X$ and all $\lambda\in\mathbb R$
$$ x=0 \iff f(x) =0 \iff \|f(x)\|=0 \tag1$$
$$\|f(\lambda x)\|= \| \lambda f(x)\| = |\lambda| \|f(x)\|   \tag2$$
$$\|f(x+y)\|= \|   f(x)+f(y)\| \le   \|f(x)\| +\|f(y)\|   \tag3$$
where in every line, the first step is based on the properties of $f$, and the second is based on the properties of $\|\cdot\|$.

That said, writing in full sentences may actually be preferable. Depends on where this proof goes.